# Setting onclick dynamically and passing in the element itself to access innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm dynamically creating some `<div>` elements and then filling their `innerHTML` properties with text. I'm trying to set their `onclick` event handlers like this:

```
myDiv.onclick = function() { alert("Hello!") };
```

That I can do. What I would like to do is be able to access the value / innerHTML (new to JavaScript and DOM, so I'm unsure of what term is what I'm looking for) within the newly defined `onclick` function. How would I go about accessing the data of `myDiv` within the function being defined for its `onclick` property? `myDiv` will be something simple like:

```
<div>StackOverflow</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Contents" is the correct term I think.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The onclick handler is executed in the context of the element.

```
myDiv.onclick = function () { alert(this.innerHTML); };
```

Comment: Doh! This must have been the only thing I didn't try. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Inside the handler, `this` will refer to the element.

```
myDiv.onclick = function() { alert(this.innerHTML) };
```

[Tadaaa :).](http://jsfiddle.net/8NnAy/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is:

```
myDiv.onclick = function () { 
    alert(this.innerHTML); 
    };
```

Personally I'd stay away from innerText (due to browser issues) and use innerHTML as a rule