# Pass element as argument when creating event via DOM - JS Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, this

I'm trying to create HTML elements usingn DOM. I need to pass the `<li>` element to the `toogle` method as follows:

```html
<ul>
<li onclick="toogle(this)"><a>Some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I do it?

Current code that doesn't work:

```js
var li = document.createElement("li");                  
li.onclick = toogle(this);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Setting onclick dynamically and passing in the element itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181684/javascript-setting-onclick-dynamically-and-passing-in-the-element-itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.onclick = function () { toogle(this); };
```

Comment: I eventually got to this solution and I think it is the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
li.onclick = toogle(this);
```

actually EXECUTES that `toogle` function, and assigns its return value to the onclick. If you want your function to be called AS the click handler, then it should be

```
li.onclick = toogle;
```

Comment: I'm trying to pass the element `<li>` as an argument to the `toggle` method. This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.addEventListener('click', toogle);
```

Which will call `toogle` on click. This is the better way to do it.

and then you can get the element with:

```
function toogle(e) {
  // "e.target" will represent the element
}
```

Or if you want it your way then you can do:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.onclick = toogle;
```

and then you get the element with:

```
function toogle() {
  // "this" will represent the element
}
```

Comment: Not useful. You just ignored that I need to pass the element itself as an argument.

Comment: If you use `onclick` then `this` will represent the element when the functions called and if you use `addEventListener` then you can you the passed on argument (let's call it `e`) to get the element `e.target`.

Comment: I've made a edit to my answer and added a example for how you can get the element.

Answer (score 0):

The Snippet below demonstrates how to pass an element that was clicked by using [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). Details are commented in source.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var li = document.createElement("li");

// Needs to be in DOM before you can click it
document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(li);

// Assigning class for testing
li.className = 'klass';

// Add click event for li
li.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  // event.target is always the element that was clicked
  var tgt = e.target;

  // Verifying that the li was passed
  console.log(tgt.className);

  // klass
}, false);
```

```css
li {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```